# getting parts of url window.location

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Can someone help me with url hash? 
I use this code to get the current url and then send the data as json, but the hash part seems to be stripped then.
i tryed to use href and hash and i always get the default.aspx but no hash part like #anchor.

```
var location = String(window.location);
var title = String(document.title);
var text = { 'url': location, 'title': title };
```

**Thanks for help guys. I figured it out. All answers were correct as well as my code. I just put it in wrong event hadler. Because my hash parts are generating dynamically. Sorry for disturbing you guys!!!**

Comment: How are you checking what's in your `text` object? On client side, or on server side? Maybe you're doing something wrong on the server side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must be doing something wrong. You're not showing us all the code involved.  Here is a test page: http://gutfullofbeer.net/location.html#something

When you click that link, what do you see?

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the `window.location` object. It has these properties:

> assign: function () { [native code] }
>
> hash: "#test"
>
> host: "stackoverflow.com"
>
> hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
>
> href: "[getting parts of url window.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538697/getting-parts-of-url-window-location#test)"
>
> pathname: "/questions/2538697/getting-parts-of-url-window-location"
>
> port: ""
>
> protocol: "http:"
>
> reload: function () { [native code] }
>
> replace: function () { [native code] }
>
> search: ""

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`?

`window.location` is an object, `window.location.href` is a string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure by the comment in your question, but did you try `window.location.hash`?